# getting NullPointerException while calling SessionFactory in JSP page

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-context

While calling `qs.getSubList()` method occurring below exception. don't know why it is showing error, while calling same method from other class its work perfectly and return `Question` list.

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()" because "this.sessionFactory" is null
```

**queType.jsp**

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="com.guru.onlineexam.entity.Question"%>
<%@page import="com.guru.onlineexam.service.QuestionService"%>
<%
    QuestionService qs = new QuestionService();
    List<Question> qList = qs.getSubList();
    out.println(qList);
%>
```

**QuestionService.java**

```
@Service
public class QuestionService {

    @Autowired
    MainDao mainDao;

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

 public List<Question> getSubList() {
        // Session session = mainDao.getSession();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        String query = "SELECT DISTINCT que_subject FROM Question";
        Query q = session.createQuery(query);
        List<Question> sublist = q.getResultList();

        return sublist;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

It's showing you the error because you use the instance of `QuestionService` made by yourself and not by Spring.

To make properties of the service initialized you need to get the instance ftom the Spring context or pass it to the autowiring factory.

Although, scriptlets in JSP are descouaraged, you should write something like this in your controller component

```
QuestionService qs = AppContext.getBean(QuestionService.class);
```

then check the property of your `sessionFactory`. It should not be `null`.